# How does a Lisp macro extend the syntax and semantics of the Lisp programming language?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

A book [1] that I am reading says this:

> One of the most interesting developments in programming languages has
> been the creation of extensible languages—languages whose syntax and
> semantics can be changed within a program. One of the earliest and
> most commonly proposed schemes for language extension is the macro
> definition.

Would you give an example (along with an explanation) of a Lisp macro that extends the syntax and semantics of the Lisp programming language, please?

[1] *The Theory of Parsing, Translation, and Compiling, Volume 1 Parsing* by Aho and Ullman, page 58.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Picture the scene: it is 1958, and FORTRAN has just been invented.  Lit only by the afterglow of atomic tests, primitive Lisp programmers are writing loops in primitive Lisp the way primitive FORTRAN programmers always had:

```
(prog ((i 0))                           ;i is 0
  start                                 ;label beginning of loop
  (if (>= i 10)
      (go end))                         ;skip to end when finished
  (do-hard-sums-on i)                   ;hard sums!
  (setf i (+ i 1))                      ;increment i
  (go start)                            ;jump to start
  end)                                  ;end
```

(Except, of course this would all be in CAPITALS because lower-case had not been invented then, and the thing I wrote as `setf` would be something uglier, because `setf` (a macro!) also had not been invented then).

Enter, in clouds of only-slightly toxic smoke from their jetpack, another Lisp programmer who had escaped to 1958 from the future.  'Look', they said, 'we could write this strange future thing':

```
(defmacro sloop ((var init limit &optional (step 1)) &body forms)
  (let ((<start> (make-symbol "START")) ;avoid hygiene problems ...
        (<end> (make-symbol "END"))
        (<limit> (make-symbol "LIMIT")) ;... and multiple evaluation problems
        (<step> (make-symbol "STEP")))
    `(prog ((,var ,init)
            (,<limit> ,limit)
            (,<step> ,step))
       ,<start>
       (if (>= ,var ,<limit>)
           (go ,<end>))
       ,@forms
       (setf ,var (+ ,var ,<step>))
       (go ,<start>)
       ,<end>)))
```

'And now', they say, 'you can write this':

```
(sloop (i 0 10)
  (do-hard-sums i))
```

And thus were simple loops invented.

Back here in the future we can see what this loop expands into:

```
(sloop (i 0 10)
  (format t "~&i = ~D~%" i))
->
(prog ((i 0) (#:limit 10) (#:step 1))
 #:start (if (>= i #:limit) (go #:end))
      (format t "~&i = ~D~%" i)
      (setf i (+ i #:step))
      (go #:start)
 #:end)
```

Which is the code that the primitive Lisp programmers used to type in by hand.  And we can run this:

```
> (sloop (i 0 10)
    (format t "~&i = ~D~%" i))
i = 0
i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
i = 4
i = 5
i = 6
i = 7
i = 8
i = 9
nil
```

And in fact *this is how loops work in Lisp today*.  If I try a simple `do` loop, one of Common Lisp's predefined macros, we can see what it expands into:

```
(do ((i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((>= i 10))
  (format t "~&i = ~D~%" i))
->
(block nil
  (let ((i 0))
    (declare (ignorable i))
    (declare)
    (tagbody
     #:g1481 (if (>= i 10) (go #:g1480))
             (tagbody (format t "~&i = ~D~%" i)
                      (setq i (+ i 1)))
             (go #:g1481)
     #:g1480)))
```

Well, this expansion is not the same and it uses constructs I haven't talked about, but you can see the important thing: this loop has been rewritten to use `GO`.  And, although Common Lisp does not define the expansion of it's looping macros, it is almost certainly the case that all the standard ones expand into something like this (but more complicated in general).

In other words: *Lisp doesn't have any primitive looping constructs*, but all such constructs are added to the language by macros.  These macros as well as other macros to extend the language in other ways, can be written by users: they do not have to be provided by the language itself.

Lisp is a *programmable* programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, perhaps the explanations will be terse, but you could look at the macros used in the lisp language itself, `defun`, for example.

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defun.htm

In lisp, macros are a big part of the language itself, basically allowing you to rewrite code before it's compiled.

Answer (score 0):

There's more than just macros defined by defmacro. There are also Reader Macros ! as Paul Graham said in [On Lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html) :

> The three big moments in a Lisp expression’s life are read-time,
> compile-time, and runtime. Functions are in control at runtime. Macros
> give us a chance to perform transformations on programs at
> compile-time. …read-macros… do their work at read-time.
>
> Macros and read-macros see your program at different stages. Macros
> get hold of the program when it has already been parsed into Lisp
> objects by the reader, and read-macros operate on a program while it
> is still text. However, by invoking read on this text, a read-macro
> can, if it chooses, get parsed Lisp objects as well. Thus read-macros
> are at least as powerful as ordinary macros.

With Reader Macros, you can define new semantics way beyond ordinary macros, like for example :

- adds support for string interpolation ( [cl-interpol](http://weitz.de/cl-interpol/) )
- adds support for JSON directly into the language : See [this article](https://lisper.in/reader-macros) to know more.